# How to group by unique id, take the values from a row and set up as columns where we add values of another column to correspond row

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse

For example the dataset looks like this

```
ID|Occurence|Name  
 1        X  James
 1       XP  Harry  
 2        X  James
 2       XP  Harry
 2       RQ  William
 3       XP  Harry
 3       RQ  William
 3       PS  Diana
 3        X  James
 4       PS  Diana
```

New dataset should look like this. I believe i would group_by the ID and pivot_wider but not sure how to get the values as columns and add the corresponding "Name" values as inputs

```
ID|X    |XP     |RQ       |PS   |
 1 James Harry   
 2 James Harry   William   
 3 James Harry   William   Diana
 4                         Diana
```

Comment: This is exactly pivot_wide. `Name` is your value column `Occurance` is the column to pivot.

Comment: How would i input that?

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_wider(your_data, names_from = Occurence, values_from = Name)`

Comment: the reshape script from the link provided assumes there are three columns is there a way to write the script and have it select the three columns from a larger dataset?

Comment: Otherwise it works i set up my dataset to just include the three columns from the larger dataset.